# Controller to Model to Controller login issue

Tags: codeigniter

This is a confusing topic but here is the scenario.  I have a web application that consists of the same set of pages, whether a user decides to login or not.  Two buttons login in or guest.  When the user clicks login, they are sent to a MODEL function that checks to see if they are logged in and if not uses ldap to get them logged in.  Now after that function I have a function call to continue to the next function/page.  That function doesnt get executed after the user leaves the model.  So when I press that button "log in" the second time, it does go to the next page, because the user is logged in.

Essentially how do I get the login function to return to the new function in the controller

```
       if($submit == "Login") {

     $postData['suppress'] = "No";
     $this->Login->requireLogin();//login using ldap
     $this->session->set_userdata(array('is_user' => TRUE));
     $this->Tests->setAccountNumber($_SESSION['accountNumber']);
     $this->Userr->setAccountNumber($_SESSION['accountNumber']);
     $this->main();
     //not hitting main function until we hit login again
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `redirect('controller/main')` to send the user on, so that it will trigger another request after the user is logged in.